# BASH pass argument to function doesn't work

Tags: bash, function, shell

I try to pass an argument to the function install() but the output is "add" and not my argument.
I don't know how to get just the REP when i call the function directory-install(), because for know i have all the phrase "add directory...."

```
function install () {

    echo $1 #output not ok, show "add"

}


function directory-install () {

    read -p "enter directory " REP
    if cd $REP 2> /dev/null ; then
        echo -e "add directory '$REP'\n"
    else
        mkdir REP
        echo -e "creat directory \n"
    fi
    echo $REP
}


REP=$(directory-install)
echo $REP #output not ok too show "add directory..." but i just want the REP .
install $REP
```

Comment: Is the issue that you left out `()` after `function directory-install`?

Comment: @DaveYarwood make an edit of my problem

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something... but where do you actually call `install`?  (Edit: OP edited their code)

Comment: @Mr.Llama at the end of the script

Comment: Bash functions should be *either* `f()` *or* `function f`.

Comment: you refer sometimes to REP, sometimes to $REP - which one is the correct one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `install` function is working 100% correctly, the problem is that you're passing it garbage.  Garbage in, garbage out.

The real culprit is your `directory-install` function.  When you execute `REP=$(directory-install)`, the variable `REP` now contains *all of the text output* from `directory-install`, not just the final `echo $REP`.  That means the `add directory` or `creat directory` text.

If you want `directory-install` to *only* return `REP`, then you need to make sure that you have *no other output* in the function call.  Alternately, you can redirect the non-return text to STDERR where it will be displayed, but not captured.

**Example:**

```
function badExample() {
    echo "Hello World"
    echo "ReturnText"
}

rtn=$(badExample)
# rtn now contains "Hello World\nReturnText"


function goodExample() {
    echo "Hello World" 1>&2
    echo "ReturnText"
}

rtn=$(goodExample)
# "Hello World" will appear on screen and rtn contains "ReturnText"
```

Comment: But if i need other output, how can i do ?

Comment: @Droïdeka - I edited the response.  You can redirect the output to STDERR where it will appear on screen but not be captured in the return.  The `1>&2` means "redirect STDOUT to STDERR".

Comment: very simple and effective ! Real thx for the explanations, the time, and the exemple you made !